# Error: cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I had added google AdMob to the project and found this error :
error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
^
symbol:   class InterstitialAd
location: package com.google.android.gms.ads

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer :
add this codes to build.gradle(app)
(in the android tag )

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0"
 }
}
```

and if you had use of admob in the one library  add codes above to library gradle too

Answer (score 9):

If you get this error after updating your `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` dependency to a more recent version, know that importing `com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd` has been deprecated since version 19.7.0 and has since been totally removed.

The new import should be:

```java
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
```

Either revert `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` to a version pre-19.7.0 or update your code by following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial.